# Rename table in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to rename a table in my app's `sqlite` database. For that I am using the following command:

```
ourDatabase.rawQuery("ALTER TABLE " + oldName + " RENAME TO " + newName,
                null);
```

where `oldName` is old name of the table, `newName` is the new name of table and `ourDatabase` is an instance of `SQLiteDatabase`. But this is not working.

What's the mistake ?

Thanks.

Comment: Which version you are using, update your version, it works from 3.0 only

Comment: The official documentation says that android ships with version 3.4.0. So in any case, the sqlite version greater than 3.4
In that case, the above code should work ?

Comment: Yeah, if so it would work, Do you have any crash or error code running this query, did it executes successfully?

Comment: Yeah, it executed successfully. No crash, nothing. Neither do I have any error.

Comment: Try this `ALTER TABLE database_name.table_name RENAME TO new_table_name;`

Comment: Now the app is crashing, with a error message that my `oldName` table does not exist. But that's not possible, because my code display the table names after reading the database and then display these names in a listView. I have added a feature in `setOnItemClickListener()` method to edit the name of table.

Comment: Ok then we can check putting tablename within ' like `ALTER TABLE 'NAME' RENAME TO 'other NAME'` the schema support so

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try `execSQL` instead of `rawQuery` like:

```
ourDatabase.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + original_table_name + " RENAME TO " + new_table_name);
```

Comment: How is this any different than the query inside the question...?

Comment: The null param for the Android rawQuery method is there for a reason. I was referring to the difference between your SQL query and his. Which is the same. The actual answer to his question is to use execSql method instead.

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 7):

Try this code:

```
    db.beginTransaction();
    try{
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + oldName + " RENAME TO " + newName+";");
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } finally{
        db.endTransaction();
    }
```